# How to get android:layout_width and android:layout_height in custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to get width and height from custom view without using custom attributes. Is it possible? I tried this solution what I found but it is crashing my app:

Error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams`

inflated XML(root) is also `FrameLayout`

My class is extending `FrameLayout`

```
companion object{
        const val MATCH_PARENT = -1
        const val WRAP_CONTENT = -2
    }

override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

        var rootWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        var rootHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        if (rootWidth == MATCH_PARENT) rootWidth = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        if (rootWidth == WRAP_CONTENT) rootWidth = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        if (rootHeight == MATCH_PARENT) rootHeight = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        if (rootHeight == WRAP_CONTENT) rootHeight = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        val rootParams = LayoutParams(rootWidth, rootHeight)
        rootParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        layoutParams = rootParams
        root.layoutParams = rootParams
    }
```

Full Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:798)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:676)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:479)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1638)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2734)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1583)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1867)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1471)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7215)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1012)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:823)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:758)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:998)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6735)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Inflated Layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonParent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buttonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Usage of this custom View Class:

```
<com.project.custom.LoadingButton
            android:id="@+id/progressButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            style="@style/button_round_grey"
            app:l_buttonText="@string/btn_text_2"
            />
```

Comment: Check your imports I think by mistake you have imported `LinearLayout$LayoutParams` instead of `FrameLayout$LayoutParams` in your `custom FrameLayout`

Comment: Its FrameLayout

Comment: What is `root`?

Comment: root is parent of inflated XML layout. It is FrameLayout. But also class where this layout is inflated is FrameLayout. So I have to set layoutParams for both of them. Its working like FrameLayout inside FrameLayout. But true parent is not visible in XML it is class itself.

Comment: In which line do you have the cast issue?

Comment: It is not telling me any line

Comment: If I add layoutParams = rootParams to comment it is working without crash. But View width and height is not changed. I need to set parent width and height aswell.

Comment: Try to post the significant part of the layout. There is something strange because `LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)`

Comment: Done. This is layout xml inflated inside Class. Also added usage anywhere in any layout in my app. I needed Default progress button because it is not supported by Android (idk why they cant add progress button view)

Comment: A `View` should not be setting its own `LayoutParams`. That's up to the parent. The crash is happening because you're presumably setting `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` on your custom `View` that is inside a `LinearLayout`. Why are you trying to set the `LayoutParams` like that in the first place? That is, what are you trying to accomplish, ultimately?

Comment: Because if I set it only for inner FrameLayout (that one from XML). It will not change real button width and height (I set style in XML - > style has rounded background drawable inside. This style is applied to class FrameLayout). If I set width and height for root, it will not resize background for button (it stays match_parent). If I set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` it is still `match_parent` in App

Comment: This is an XY problem, then. Your issue is the redundant `<FrameLayout>` in the custom `View`'s internal layout. Your `View` _is_ the `FrameLayout`. The other one is pointless. Replace the `<FrameLayout>` tags with `<merge>` tags, which will cause those child `View`s to be added directly to your custom `View`.

Comment: This is solution what I wanted. Thanks. It fixed alot of issues what I faced with styles.